# Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: inputnum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've inherited another developer's code for a project I'm working on. Here's an example of their code - notice the first comment...

```
function disableSuggestButton(themePath) {
    // could not see a better way of doing this :(
    var row = $("input[type='text']:inputnum:inputnumsmall");
    $(row).each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("disabled") == true) {
            var btn = $(this).closest("tr").find(".btnSuggest")
            $(btn).hover(function () {
                $(this).css({ backgroundImage: 'url(' + themePath + '/images/buttons/btnSuggest.png)' }).css('cursor', 'default');
            }, function () {
                $(this).css({ backgroundImage: 'url(' + themePath + '/images/buttons/btnSuggest.png)' }).css('cursor', 'default');
            });
            $(btn).removeAttr("title").removeAttr("href");
        }
    });
}
```

I needed to upgrade the version of jQuery (from 1.3.2 to 1.4) however when doing this the following line:

```
var row = $("input[type='text']:inputnum:inputnumsmall");
```

produces the following error:

> Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   inputnum

How can I improve on the previous devloper's selector? inputnum & inputnumsmall are CSS classes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the previous developers written some custom selectors? (maybe right into the jquery file?).

You should just be able to do:

```
var row = $("input[type='text'].inputnum.inputnumsmall");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BqHBf/